# Odd behavior with pandas and to_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, utf-8

I ran into an interesting thing today with using pandas to_csv() that I'm not sure is intended behavior. I thought I'd put it up here and see if anyone had any thoughts.

I had a data set with some text in it and some utf-8 encoded characters.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file',encoding='utf-8)
#Do some work
with open('file','w') as f:
    pd.to_csv(f , encoding ='utf-8')
```

This would throw an ascii encoding error that made me feel like an idiot
If I switched to this pattern :

```
file_out = 'file.csv'
pd.to_csv(file_out,encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Worked just fine.

Any ideas if this is intended behavior ?

Comment: What error, exactly? It always helps to post the **full stack trace**

Comment: ascii encoding error , i don't have a full trace right now but will try to get a minimum working example together tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing quote.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8')

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    pd.to_csv(f, encoding='utf-8')
```

Additionally, you should not add spaces between the parameters and passed values. Also, add the file ending to the file you are passing.

Comment: Let's assume for a minute that the code was able to compile and run. I'm specifically asking if the python pattern of " with file  as f : followed by pd.to_csv(f) " is incompatible